# Use C function in C++ program; "multiply-defined" error

Tags: c++, c, include, compiler-errors

I am trying to use [this code for the Porter stemming algorithm](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/c.txt) in a C++ program I've already written. I followed the instructions near the end of the file for using the code as a separate module. I created a file, stem.c, that ends after the definition and has

```
extern int stem(char * p, int i, int j) ...
```

It worked fine in Xcode but it does not work for me on Unix with gcc 4.1.1--strange because usually I have no problem moving between the two. I get the error

> ld: fatal: symbol `stem(char*, int, int)' is multiply-defined:
>           (file /var/tmp//ccrWWlnb.o type=FUNC; file /var/tmp//cc6rUXka.o type=FUNC);
>   ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to cluster

I've looked online and it seems like there are many things I could have wrong, but I'm not sure what combination of a header file, extern "C", etc. would work.

Comment: Are you somehow #incude'ing that C file in other files ? What's the command lines you use to compile/link your program ?

Comment: Yes, in one function's .cpp file I have #include "stem.c". Compiling with g++ Whatever.cpp Anotherthing.cpp stem.c -o myprogram.

Comment: Well there's your problem! By the way, this has nothing whatsoever to do with mixing C and C++. The same thing would happen if you had `#include` ed one .cpp file inside another.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That error means that the symbol (stem) is **defined** in more than one module.

You can **declare** the symbol in as many modules as you want.  A **declaration** of a function looks like this:

```
int stem(char * p, int i, int j);
```

You don't need the "extern" keyword, although it doesn't hurt anything.  For functions declarations, it's implied.

A **definition** of a function looks like this:

```
int stem(char * p, int i, int j) 
{
    /* body of your function */
}
```

The "multiply-defined" error indicates that you have two modules with a **definition** for the same function.  That usually means that you have two files that define the function, or two files that #include a file that defines the function.  Normally, you should not put function definitions in files that you #include.  Put the **definition** in a .c, .cpp, or .cc file and just put a **declaration** in a .h file that you #include.

For example, you could create a stem.h file with this in it:

```
int stem(char * p, int i, int j);
```

Then, `#include "stem.h"`.

Comment: Of course! I was getting so distracted by the unfamiliar aspects of the C code that I didn't see this. Thank you. I'm getting a new error doing it this way in Xcode, but it works in Unix which is the important thing.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Whatever.cpp has #include "stem.c" provides the first definition, and specifying stem.c on the compiler command line provides the second definition.

You should break up stem.c into a header file (With just function prototypes) and a .c file which contains the implemention. Include only the header file in Whatever.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "C". You need to extern "C" { ... } and only actually define the function once. But you can declare it (the prototype) as often as you like.

Comment: The first part of this really isn't true for the case of this question. You only need `extern "C"` if you need a C++ function to be able to be called from C code. In this case, it's the other way around and a C function is being called from C++ code.